# What are the other ways of storing and accessing the webelement(locators) during automation testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I'm aware and have also used two ways of storing the WebElements/locators (a.k.a Object Repository)

1. External File (example: .properties , .yaml, .xml, etc...or any other file type)
2. Using page factory inside a Page Class (POM)

My question is are there any other way/approach used to store the Object Repository(Locators).

For example: Is it advisable to store all the locators(as instance of By Class) for a web application in a class(lets call this class as ObjectRepository) and directly inherit or call those locators in our Test Class.

*Sample Code Below:*

```
public class ObjectRepository {

    //locators for login page
    public By byUserNameTextboxID = By.id("username");
    public By byPasswordTextboxID = By.id("password");
    public By byLoginButtonName   = By.name("submit");
}
```

**Edit 1:** Current Framework is something like this.

(Class on the Left is inherited by Right)

> SeleniumWrapper Class >> ObjectRepositoryLoginPage Class >>
>   TestLoginPage

**SeleniumWrapper Class** - Holds all the selenium methods in custom methods *Example:*
`public void click(By by) {
    driver.findElement(by).click(); 
}`

**ObjectRepository Class** - Holds all the WebElements as a object of By Class *Example:*
`By byUsernameTextboxID = By.id("username");`

**TestLoginPage Class** - Contains methods related to testing the LoginPage. *Example:*
`click(byUsernameTextboxID)`

Comment: So if you have 1000 locators in total, why would you  inherit 1000 class variables in each page class? Where each page class might require just 20-30 variables(locators).

Comment: @VishalAggarwal agree. Would you suggest a separate ObjectRepository for each class.For example: `ObjectRepositoryForLoginPage` and `ObjectRepositoryForCustomerPage` My intention of asking the (original) question is becoz I am facing a lot of problem in maintaining the pageFactory in my POM framework. Thanks.

Comment: There is no 'one shoe fits all' solution , every solution depend on given situation which I don't know in your case.I think it would be more beneficial if you share specific details about your implementation and ask about specific problems you are facing in maintenance of page factory.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I have updated the question to add description of the current framework that I am using. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Alok, I would have one page class per r each page in the application which will encapsulate objects and methods related to that page. All the methods would be high level application level service methods like Login, Logout, Place order, CancelOrder instead of UI level like clickButton. Also I would not have separate Object Repository class.

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

Answer (score 1):

If you are up for using Ruby say, you could:

store the name and locators as key-value pairs in a .yml file

Create a Page Object class with an `initialize` method that read the YAML file and dynamically adds the methods to the new instance of the class.

Make the initialize method go through each line of the file and dynamically add the method to the class.

Now your instance of `PageObject` will have these available as methods.

Code samples:

`page_object.rb
class PageObject
  def initialize
    load_page_object_file('spec/support/page_objects.yml')
  end 
  private
  def load_page_object_file(file)
    page_object = YAML.load(File.read(file))
    page_object.each do |k, v|
      define_singleton_method(k) do v end 
    end 
  end 
end`

`spec/support/page_objects.yml`
`(Examples)`
`...
  primary_phone: 'input#PrimaryPhone'
  title: 'div.title-module'
  last_name: 'StudentLastName'
  ...`

Usage:

within a spec

  `describe "stuff" do
  ...
  p = PageObject.new
    it "stuff" do
      fill_in p.last_name, with: 'testLast'
      fill_in p.title, with: 'MR'
      fill_in p.phone, with: '6175551212'`

Comment: Hi Thanks...for the answer...I wanted to know if there is another way to store locators other than the external files(ex: .properties, .yml, etc.). sorry if I confused you. I have updated my question.

Comment: If you don't have external files you either have them at the bottom of the test file (but how to share?) or you have them inline (hard to maintain consistently and how to share across test files?  Either way won't work well for most suites.

Answer (score 0):

The another way of using object repositories in Selenium webdriver other than properties file is through XML file.
Properties file is a text file where the data are stored in the form of key-value pairs whereas in XML file data can be stored in the form of DOM(Document object model).

Comment: Thanks shanila, as I mentioned in the question I am looking for any other approach other than POM and External files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby, you could:

store the name and locators as key-value pairs in a .yml file

Create a Page Object class with an initialize method that reads the YAML file and dynamically adds the methods to the new instance of the class.

Make the initialize method go through each line of the file and dynamically add the method to the class.

Now your instance of PageObject will have these available as methods.

Code samples:

page_object.rb class PageObject def initialize load_page_object_file('spec/support/page_objects.yml') end private def load_page_object_file(file) page_object = YAML.load(File.read(file)) page_object.each do |k, v| define_singleton_method(k) do v end end end end

spec/support/page_objects.yml
(Examples)
... primary_phone: 'input#PrimaryPhone' title: 'div.title-module' last_name: 'StudentLastName'

Usage:

within a spec describe "stuff" do ... p = PageObject.new it "stuff" do fill_in p.last_name, with: 'testLast' fill_in p.title, with: 'MR' fill_in p.phone, with: '6175551212'